# As per the latest canon, is Jango Fett still Jaster Mereel's protégé /adopted son?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars

Specifically in relation to Satine Kryz's *New Mandalorians*, Jaster Mereel's *True Mandalorians* and Tor Vizsla's *Death Watch*?

The Clone Wars wiki seems to imply that the TV series has combined Satine Kryz's pacifist *New Mandalorians* with Jaster Mereel's honorable mercs, the *True Mandalorians* and implies Satine as Jaster's political successor.

> The New Mandalorians were a large group of Mandalorians led by Duchess Satine Kryze and before that Jaster Mereel, who were pacifists. The Death Watch despised them and wanted to "liberate" Mandalore from them on numerous occasions.

and

> By the time of the Clone Wars Era, the Mandalorians had renounced the violence and desire for conquest which haunted most of their history. Under the leadership of Jester Mereel who authored the Supercommando Codex the people of Mandalore became friends of the Republic. However not all Mandalorians stood with Mereel and his attempt to civilize a savage society and so a splinter faction known as the Death Watch was formed.

In older EU, according to Wookieepedia, however, Jaster's political successor is *Jango Fett*, though all of his faction wiped out by the Jedi thanks to a dirty trick by the *Death Watch*

> Jango Fett succeeded [Jaster Mereel] as the new Mand'alor and leader of the True Mandalorians until the devastating defeat at the Battle of Galidraan against the Jedi Order. There, a Death Watch scheme unfolded that brought a contingent of Jedi Knights led by Master Dooku to the planet under the false pretenses that the True Mandalorians were murdering civilians. When the Jedi attempted to take them into custody, fighting broke out that left eleven Jedi and every True Mandalorian on Galidraan dead, save for Jango Fett.

and

> After being imprisoned by Jedi, Fett was responsible for destroying the Death Watch, a Mandalorian group who killed Fett's mentor, Jaster Mereel.

As such, according to the latest canon on Mandalorian history as provided by only the Clone Wars TV series (or other canon of the same level) is Jango Fett still the adopted son/protégé of Jaster Mereel?

Edited in 2021: I'm curious how things have changed with whatever's the latest in the post-Disney world of Star Wars, what with more Mandalorian lore coming in from "The Mandalorian", and earlier stuff like Rebels, post-Clone Wars.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** Most likely, yes, but with a few changes.

---

**Long Answer:**

I'm not up to speed on The Clone Wars show, but the history you've quoted from it definitely conflicts with what we knew prior to the show. In Jango Fett: Open Seasons, it is clearly explained that the Mandalorians IN GENERAL are split into two factions - the True Mandalorians led by Jaster Mereel and the Death Watch led by Vizla. There was no mention of the third faction, and Jaster's faction were definitely NOT pacifists. In fact, the primary difference between the two was simply a matter of honor - Jaster liked to pick & choose the jobs his people took, whereas the Death Watch would take any job, even resorting to piracy and genocide if needed. Keep in mind the quote you used is from a wiki, so that may just be a fan lumping Satine and Jaster together incorrectly.

Here's what we knew before the show. During an ambush by the Death Watch, (possible spoilers)

> A young Jango's family is killed by the Death Watch during one of the early skirmishes between them and Jaster's True Mandalorian faction. A vengeful Jango then showed tremendous spirit & skill facing the Death Watch members. Impressed with the boy, Jaster adopts him as his son/protege and raises him. Years later on a mission, Jaster is killed on the battlefield and Jango assumes his mantle of
>  leadership. Jango then leads the True Mandalorians for several years
>  until the Battle of Galidran, which sees the last united group of Mandalorians wiped out.

For the next 30 years, until Boba Fett later unites them again during the Yuuzhan Vong invasion, the Mandalorians are a scattered and nearly extinct people with no leadership. Now, obviously, this doesn't jive with The Clone Wars and its concept of a peaceful, united Mandalorian society back on the homeworld.

However, any time there's a conflict between EU material and a Lucas source, the Lucas source wins by default. So in this case, the events of The Clone Wars would seem to now be the "official" history of the Mandalorian people. *sigh*.

However, to more directly answer your question, there are some references in episodes of The Clone Wars which infer that Jango/Boba is still considered the adopted son/successor of Jaster Mereel, at least in spirit if not political role.

From what I've been able to glean so far, one of the few references to Jaster in The Clone Wars was made in regards to the armor previously worn by Jango Fett. It therefore stands to reason that most (if not all) of the previous continuity might be retained. After all, if the armor worn by Jango still originated with Jaster, then maybe we can fit in the rest with a little massaging & lube. It also appears that the New Mandalorian faction rose to prominence AFTER the events of Open Seasons, which could conceivably allow the two continuities to co-exist with only minor tweaking.

For example, the leader of the Death Watch - Pre Vizla - could be a relative of the Tor Vizla featured in Open Seasons. It's possible that he united the remnants of the Death Watch after the events of Open Seasons. Considering the new EU policy under Disney, it's really up in the air for now. Both Boba Fett and the Mandalorian people in general are set to be featured heavily in the new show "Rebels" so maybe it will be addressed there.